# How to get the Vendor Name column from purchase order in suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Disclaimer: I'm a NetSuite newbie.

I need to return both the item and the vendor name for all items in a purchase order.  I Googled around and found this search.

The search works as desired.

```
var purchaseorderSearchObj = search.create({
  type: "purchaseorder",
  filters: [
    ["type","anyof","PurchOrd"], 'and',
['mainline','is','F'],'and',
['tranId','is',targetTranId.toString()]
  ],
  columns: [
    search.createColumn(
      { name: "itemid", join: "item" }
    )
  ]
});
```

Now I need to add the Vendor Name column to the search.

I look for the purchase order objects description, and found it here (http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/script/record/purchaseorder.html).

I then try to modify the search by doing something like:

```
columns: [
        search.createColumn(
           {name: "itemid",join: "item"},
           {name: "vendorname", join "item"})
      ]
```

. . . with no good result.  I've tried `{name: "vendorname"}`, `{ name: "vendorname", join: "vendor"}`, and other permutations.

1. What properties should I use for the 'columns' attribute to return item and vendorname?
2. How do I learn which columns need joining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `search.createColumn()` again to create a new column:

```
columns: [
    search.createColumn(
       {name: "itemid",join: "item"}),
    search.createColumn(
       {name: "vendorname", join: "item"})
  ]
```